# Is the Mayor aware of the fact that she is the Evil Queen in Once Upon a Time?

Tags: plot-explanation, once-upon-a-time

I've just finished watching Episode 12 of Season 1 of *Once Upon a Time*. As stated by Henry at the beginning of the series, everyone's memories have been erased, including the Mayor's. However, the Mayor is clearly aware that she is the Evil Queen after taking the Huntsman's heart from its box and crushing it.

Later on though, she begs Mr. Gold to tell her his real name, even though it is shown that she knew his name when she was the Evil Queen. Does this mean that she does know the truth, but some of her memories are hazy as opposed to fully erased like everyone else?

Comment: yes regina knows she's the person who cast the spell

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To the question title, yes.  Regina retains all her memories.

To the question in the body, no, her memories aren't hazy.  Regina is the one who cast the curse; from her point of view, she *should* be the only one who knows their true identity.

Due to Mr. Gold's actions in previous episodes, Regina had become suspicious that he might actually know who he really is.  She had to word it carefully so that, if Mr. Gold didn't know he was Rumplestiltskin, he wouldn't think Regina was going crazy.  But if he did know, he would answer as such, confirming her suspicions that he did remember.

Comment: Yes - after watching Ep 13, it's clearer now that she is fully aware of everything, as she is actively trying to keep David and Mary apart. As her plan is failing, she encourages Kathryn to leave so something bad will happen.

Answer (score -1):

In S03E09 (Save Henry) is shown that after adopting Henry, Regina found out that his mother was the savior,

> and she created and drank a memory potion to forget that he was the son of the savior, as she had grown attatched to him, but did not want to be associated with the savior in any way.

Comment: When did this happen?

Comment: which season you are watching now?

Comment: Completed all the broadcast ones

Comment: she drank portion in S03E09(Save Henry).

Comment: In starting of this episode we see the flashback of adopting henry.

Comment: While this is correct, it fails to answer the question _and_ contains a major spoiler for a time much later

Answer (score -5):

Regina forgot what happened too, so she asks Mr.Gold what his real name was.

Comment: Nope the answer accepted by OP is correct, Welcome to Movies this question already has a valid answer there are plenty of unanswered questions in the site which might use your help.

Comment: Just to be clear, though, contributing answers to a question even when one has alrady been accepted isn't always a bad thing, but the new answer should provide something both valid and substantial to warrant being added.